# Content not showing up on detailed view in Django

Tags: python, django

**UPDATE #1:**

I'm still having some issues, I'm getting some of the content using tags like `{{object.title}}`, but content that I've included using `{% include "sidebar.html" %}` and `{% include "slider.html" %}` are not showing up.

**Part of my sidebar.html looks like this:**

```
        <div class="navItem">
            <div class="overlay">
            </div><!-- /.overlay -->
                <a href="{%url "detailed" slug=article.slug %}"><img src="{{article.relatedImage}}" alt="" class="navPicture"></a>
            <a href="{%url "detailed" slug=article.slug %}"><p class="navTitle">{{article.title|truncatewords:"4"}}</p></a>
        </div><!-- /.navItem -->
```

I'm doing a class assignment and I'm using the same tags as I have on my main page on my detailed page in Django, but the actual content on the detailed page is not showing up when I use the {{tags}}.

**Snippet of detailed.html**

```
<p class="date">{{article.pubDate|date:"l, F j, Y" }}</p> | <a href="" class="author">{{article.author}}</a>
<img src="{{article.heroImage}}" alt="" class="largeImage">
<div class="contentBlock">
    <img src="{{article.relatedImage}}" alt="" class="relatedImage">
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from . import models 

# Create your views here.
class BlogIndex(generic.ListView):
    queryset = models.FullArticle.objects.published()
    template_name = "list.html"

class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.FullArticle
template_name = "detailed.html"
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.BlogIndex.as_view(), name="list"), url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name="detailed"),
)
```

Screenshot of list.html: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VfiH.jpg

Screenshot of detailed.html: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbb6b.jpg

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that ``\S+`` means one or more white spaces? Perhaps you meant ``\w+``?

Comment: Yes, I am aware. How does this relate to my problem?

Comment: Because it means that your detail URL only accepts spaces for the slug. I'm sure that isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `{{ article }}` in your template. Which is undefined. Either user `{{ object }}`, either specify `context_object_name = 'article'` in your Detail View.

Moreover, you are using white spaces for identifying your objects??? i.e. you are doing stuff like `models.FullArticle.objects.get(pk=' ')` which is really weird.

Comment: I've tried using tags like {{object.title}} in my slider.html and sidebar.html, but it doesn't grab the content from Django's database. So, can you be more specific about how I can use `context_object_name = 'article'` in my detailed view to solve my problem.

Comment: just set it as I told you. ``context_object_name`` is a class level variable. Initiate it with `article` to name the object. Nevertheless, this isn;t the source of the problem. Try doing ``(?P<pk>`` instead of ``slug``

Comment: You're going to have to break this down a bit further for me. Could you give me step by step instruction?

Answer (score -1):

Mihai zamfir was right.

Here's the full code - this should be in your views.py

```
class FoodDetail(DetailView)
    model = FoodPost
    context_object_name = 'post'
    template_name = 'views/detail-views/food-details.html'
```

for urls.py

```
 path('posts/<str:link>/<int:pk>', FoodDetail.as_view(), name="food-detail")
```

and inside details view

```
    <h1>{{post.pk}}</h1>
```

and the template from which you are referring should be

```
<a href="{% url 'food-detail' post.link post.pk %}">read more</a>
```